# Iterator VS const_iterator, using it with distance()

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, const-iterator

Just a question, on the use of const_iterator vs just iterator.  More specifically with the use of distance().   Below is some basic code that just craps out a list of "fav_games" that the user enters (earlier in the application).  I wanted to also crap out the 'index' of the vector so as to print out a numbered list.

Partial Code:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> fav_games;
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter; // const_iterator no worky with "distance()"

    if (fav_games.size() > 0)  {
        cout << "\n\nCurrent game list: \n";
        for (iter = fav_games.begin(); iter != fav_games.end(); ++iter) 
        {
            cout << distance(fav_games.begin(), iter) << ". " << *iter << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why, "const_iterator" will not work, where I am forced to use "iterator" instead.  Looking for the 'theory' behind it.  "distance()" appears to expecting and "iterator" -- not "const_iterator". ..Why?

Just for reference the compile error if I use "const_iterator":

Error   1   error C2782: 'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type std::distance(_InIt,_InIt)' : template parameter '_InIt' is ambiguous z:\micah\c++\favgames\favgames\favgames.cpp 49  1   favgames

Thanks!

Comment: The type of both arguments of `distance` must be the same (if you deduce the template argument). So, in C++11, you had to use `.cbegin()` and a `const_iter`. You can, for RandomAccessIterators, also use `-`, e.g. `iter - fav_games.begin()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
vector<string>::const_iterator b, iter, e;

if (fav_games.size() > 0)  {
    cout << "\n\nCurrent game list: \n";
    for (b = fav_games.begin(), iter = b, e = fav_games.end(); iter != e; ++iter) 
    {
        cout << distance(b, iter) << ". " << *iter << endl;
    }
}
```

`distance` has no problem with two `const_iterator` instances, or two `iterator` instances.  Your mistake was in mixing them.

Still, making `O(n)` calls to `distance` is crazy.  Just use a counter:

```
vector<string>::const_iterator iter, e;
size_t i;

if (fav_games.size() > 0)  {
    cout << "\n\nCurrent game list: \n";
    for (i = 0, iter = fav_games.begin(), e = fav_games.end(); iter != e; (++iter), (++i)) 
    {
        cout << i << ". " << *iter << endl;
    }
}
```

In C++11 and later, one may of course go one step further and avoid explicit use of the iterators at all:

```
if (fav_games.size() > 0) {
    int i = 0;
    cout << "\n\nCurrent game list: \n";
    for (const string& game : fav_games) 
    {
        cout << (i++) << ". " << game << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @dyp: The call is inside a loop.  How's that O(1)?  Yes, distance is cheap for RandomIterator, but the simple counter is cheaper yet, and won't get mysteriously expensive if the container changes.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. However, why are you concerned with the performance of a pointer subtraction in each iteration, as opposed to an integer incrementation?

Comment: I think I see now. It's nonsense conceptually.

Comment: Nice! Avoiding the explicit use of the iterators looks nice and clean. I've not gotten that far yet with C++11, but soon hopefully :)  Thanks for all the help.